# How to insert a square root sign (i.e. $\sqrt{x}$) into a unit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am working on a paper which uses the units for the fracture toughness of a materials which are `$MPa\sqrt{m}$`. Can anyone suggest how to do this? I have tried the following:

```
\SI{1}{\mega\pascal\sqrt{m}}
```

but that just produces an error on compilation.

Comment: That works fine here, with a recently updated TeX Live 2016, `siunitx` version 2.6s.

Comment: Me too when I use my personal computer. I guess its the ancient version of SIUNITX I'm forced to use on my work network that's the culprit.

Comment: Sounds likely. I'm not familiar enough with older versions to suggest any workarounds though. Which version do you have? (Add `\listfiles`  before `\documentclass`, and a list of packages and their versions are added near the end of the `.log` file.)

Comment: You can read about math mode in the different versions of siunitx in the manual. Try updating your siunitx(and all of your LaTeX) or try `\sisetup{mode = math}`.

Comment: Version 2.5s from 2013. There's not much chance of getting an upgrade to the latex repository here in short order.

Comment: If you are unable to upgrade the system files then just copy the latest version of `siunitx.sty` to your working directory (or somewhere listed in the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable if on a unix like system). This will probably fix your problem locally. You may also need the siunitx `cfg` files, but I'd try just the style file to start with and add them in if needed. There is a small chance that this will break something, but it's very unlikely (and, if so ,you can just delete the file if this happens.)

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, but that's not going to work, because `siunitx` also need the latest version of `expl3`.

Comment: Just to confirm: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen's second suggestion (`\sisetup{mode = math}`) solves the problem for `2.5s`.

Comment: Well, if everything else fails, you may be able to wite it as `\SI{1}{\mega\pascal\metre^{1/2}}`.

Comment: I will try out @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen second suggestion next time I'm at work. Failing that I could just use plain LaTeX and write 1\,MPa$\sqrt{\mathrm{m}}.

Comment: Any news? Could you show a minimal working document?

Comment: Well, @Bobyandbob, the manuscript was desk rejected from the Elsevier journal I planned to send it to so I had to rewrite it in Word.